# Global variables not working in my contact form template?

Tags: python, django, forms

Not sure whats going on. I added a contact form to a website(it works) but when i tied it to my base.html  i noticed that my menu isnt working (#global variable) on this particular site (html looks like there is no menu at all, just div surrounding it). It buggs only in contact_form.html which contains my form. Any idea why would this happen?

#### forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Your name')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail address')
    subject = forms.CharField(label='Subject')
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Phone number')
    message = forms.CharField(label='Your message')
```

#### views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            message = cd['message']
        # construct the message body from the form's cleaned data
        body = """\
        from: %s
        name: %s
        phone: %s
        message: %s""" % (cd['email'], cd['name'], cd['phone'], cd['message'])
        send_mail(
                  cd['subject'], #subject is here
                  body, #here is the message
                  settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, # from
                  [settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL] # to
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    csrf_form = {'form': form}
    csrf_form.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('contact_form.html',csrf_form)
```

Comment: Can you post an example view that does work? I think this is going to be a RequestContext issue.

Comment: Could you please post the template (contact_form.html) as well. which django version are you using?

Comment: EDIT: pasting code here: http://pastebin.com/bff9BEWB since "Your edit couldn't be submitted"

Im using python 2.6 and django 1.3.1

Comment: might be useful to see the template snippet too if you can. If you install `django-debug-toolbar` you will be able to see all the context variables etc. which will help you debug (compare a working url to the form page and see what variables are there)

Comment: i think aganders3 was right in his first comment, i edited my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aganders3 was right.

i think i found my solution here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/

fixed the code above so it looks like:

```
return render_to_response('contact_form.html',
                          csrf_form,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                          )
```

Everything works as it supposed to now.